# MethodNotAllowedHttpException using inertia

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm using `Inertia` and `Laravel`.  I registered routes in `web.php`. When I send data to the server, I get error 405 which tells me `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` and `the PUT methods is not allowed for this route` but the data was updated successfully in database;

`in question componet.vue`

```
update(){
   this.$inertia.put(`questions/${this.id}`, this.question, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            //do some stuffs
          })
   }
```

`in QuestionsController.php`

```
 public function update(AskQuestionRequest $request, Question $question)
    {
        
        $question->update($request->only(['title', 'body']));
        return redirect()->back()->with('successMsg', 'Your Question has been updated successfully');
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally occurs when the Inertia middleware has not been installed in your app. If you recently upgraded the `inertiajs/inertia-laravel` package to `0.3.x`, you need to follow the upgrade instructions [here](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/releases/tag/v0.3.0) to install the middleware in your app.